# Linux - no sound on external sound card

Tags: linux, audio, manjaro

I have a weird problem with my Audiotrak Prodigy HD2 sound card. Recently it was working perfectly, but now when I select it in pavucontrol and play music in Clementine or watch video on youtube playback freezes. ( stuck at 0:00 even though it is supposed to be playing ) Switching to integrated card works ( sound is working as usual ). Also this sound card works as when I boot Windows, so the problem lies in linux. I have tried different profiles in pavucontrol configuration tab but that didn't seem to work.

I am using Manjaro 16.10, Kernel x86_64 Linux 4.4.39-1-MANJARO.

aplay -l:

```
card 2: ICE1724 [ICEnsemble ICE1724], device 0: ICE1724 [ICE1724]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: ICE1724 [ICEnsemble ICE1724], device 1: ICE1724 IEC958 [ICE1724 IEC958]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

lspci -v:

```
06:00.0 Multimedia audio controller: VIA Technologies Inc. VT1720/24 [Envy24PT/HT] PCI Multi-Channel Audio Controller (rev 01)
        Subsystem: VIA Technologies Inc. Device 2401
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
        I/O ports at c100 [size=32]
        I/O ports at c080 [size=128]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_ice1724
        Kernel modules: snd_ice1724
```

Comment: What did you change between "recently working perfectly" and "now has this problem"? Kernel upgrade? Pulseaudio upgrade? Alsa upgrade? When you stop pulseaudio, does playing a wav file etc. with `aplay` work?

Comment: I don't know if it may be the cause but some static discharge went from my fingers to my headphones. At first I thought that sound card got fried but it works in windows. Also aplay works with built-in audio, but doesnt when I switch to Prodigy HD2. ( No sound output )

Comment: There's a slight chance that the static discharge killed something that's used under Linux, but not under Windows, but it's a very slight chance. Next thing to test: What does `alsamixer` show for the Prodigy? Anything muted ("MM") that shouldn't be, any volume at zero? Same for `pavucontrol`: Anything accidentally muted?

Comment: It looks like prodigy driver is crashing but i don't know how to reinstall it. Also I have recorded this strange behaviour. [puush](https://puu.sh/teTP0.ogv) I will check if everything works on livecd.

Comment: Also that's how alsamixer looks for Prodigy [puush!](https://puu.sh/teWGl.png). It's weird that it doesn't show settings for analog output.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=285521) and [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1818126). Looks like an ALSA driver problem; if you can't fix it, file a bugreport for the ALSA developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution thanks to @dirkt

At first I had issued these commands in terminal:

```
#alsa --force-reload
alsaunmute
amixer set Master 90%
```

I'm not sure if it was working at this point but I also had opened alsamixer and changed Multi Track Internal Clock from "IEC958 In" to "44100" and then it started working!

Edit: I recommend setting Multi Track Rate Locking to OFF (MM) and Multi Track Rate Reset to OFF aswell ( this caused clock speed to reset to "IEC958 In" every reboot )

Thanks @dirkt again for your help.

Comment: The clock source might be actually very relevant - if there's no activity on digital out, there may be very well no clock, so nothing can work.